# Adding a keyup event to c++ textbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio, events

I am attempting to add an event handler to a textbox I have in C++, and am getting the following error:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::KeyPress::add(System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler ^)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'System::EventHandler ^' to 'System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler ^'

Here is the code I am dealing with:

```
this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(173, 31);
this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(172, 20);
this->textBox2->TabIndex = 5;
this->textBox2->KeyPress += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox2_keyUp);
```

and here is the event function:

```
private: void textBox2_keyUp(Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
  phrase = textBox2->Text;
  MyForm::HighlightedNotRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
}
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: What exactly you want to happen when the keyup event is called in the textbox?

Comment: This isn't C++, it's either C++/CX or C++/CLI and I don't know the difference in syntax well enough to tell.

Comment: When someone presses a key I want to get the text in the box, and put it into the string I have set up(phrase).  Then call my highlighting function